# jQuery getJSON cannot see console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am using the following get `getJSON`

```
$.getJSON("js/production-data.json").done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log('hello');
  });
```

I can see in Firebug that the data is being retrieved, but there is no console.log for the `response` which would be the entire data. I can't even see `hello` either.

Comment: are you getting a 200 response? remember that if you don't expect a 2XX response you should also define a `fail()` callback

Comment: Are you sure the request is completing successfully? `.done()` only runs on success. `.fail()` or `.always()` would catch a non-200 response.

Comment: @JLRishe sure it does

Comment: @JLRishe `console.log()` has always worked for me, but in this instance the above doesn't work in either Chrome or Firefox

Comment: Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: try `alert`ing and see what happens

Comment: @LuisMasuelli I am getting a `200 OK 154ms` response

Comment: NO! Never use `alert()` for trouble-shooting.

Comment: it's just to see if the code is being reached. is not a production code.

Comment: @Liam were you trying to use getJSON in your problem?

Comment: It doesn't matter @LuisMasuelli, `alert()` is not a trouble-shooting tool. The OP should use tried and true error checking methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825384/alert-is-bad-really

Comment: Have you tried adding a `fail()` handler?

Comment: @JLRishe just have and it's silently failing

Comment: This usually means the response isn't valid JSON and jQuery is failing to parse it. [Why does $.ajax call for json data trigger the error callback when http status code is “200 OK”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846086/why-does-ajax-call-for-json-data-trigger-the-error-callback-when-http-status-c)

Comment: when i am using the getJSON method and save the data response to a variable and check the variable in the console, it is incorrect, however when I just use the $.get method it saves the data to the variable as expected. On both methods however, I am unable to console.log anything.

Comment: I just verified the JSON and now it seems to work. Thanks for the tip @JLRishe to set a `fail()`

Comment: Does the result include a json content-type and is it valid json if either of these are false it will fail silently. This is why it's always best to use the $.ajax call.

Comment: @Donald It was actually Dave Ward's tip :) but I'm glad it solved your issue.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I never cared about alert being a troubleshooting tool. I suggested it just to see if he had a problem with a browser plugin or a problem with the call. Get it (for once): It is not about best practices, but about having an alleged problem with console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the callback inline, like:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
});
```

As another step, add an `always` handler, rather than only `done`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(d) {

  }).done(function(d) {
    console.log("success");
  }).fail(function(d) {
    console.log("error");
  }).always(function(d) {
    console.log("complete");
  });
```

Also get the JSON verified at [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com)