# What is the correct way to encode an inline javascript object, in order to protect it from XSS?

Tags: javascript, html, json, xss

It turns out the following which looks like valid javascript, is not:

```
<html> 
<body>
<script>
 json = {test: "</script><script>alert('hello');</script>"};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The same text, when returned JSON via an ajax api works just as expected. However when rendered in-line results in a basic XSS issues.

Given an arbitrary correct JSON string, what do I need to do server side to make it safe for in-line rendering?

**EDIT**
Ideally I would like the fix to work with the following string as well:

`json = {test: "<\/script><script>alert('hello');<\/script>"};`

Meaning, I have no idea how my underlying library is encoding the `/` char, it may have chosen to encode it, or it may have not. (so its likely a regex fix is more robust)

Comment: Basically, if you want to render it in-line, you need to make sure it doesn't contain the character sequence `</script>`.

Comment: or </ScRipt> I guess ... I worry about performance with a simple string concatenation fix and also that there may be other weird issues I am not aware of

Comment: Unless there is something strange going on, the underlying library does not escape the slash character. It has no special meaning in a Javacript string, so there is no reason to escape it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, this is not JSON at all, it's a Javascript object. JSON is a text format that is based on the Javascript syntax.

You can either make sure that the code doesn't contain the `</` character combination:

```
var obj = { test: "<"+"/script><script>alert(\"hello\");<"+"/script>" };
```

Or if you are using XHTML you can make sure that the content in the script tag is interpreted as plain data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var obj = { test: "</script><script>alert(\"hello\");</script>" };
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: corrected the phrasing in the question, feel free to step in and further correct it. The "</" -> "<" + "/" feels a little iffy performance wise, the CDATA solution is really elegant

Comment: Actually thinking about it, a server side fix of `gsub("</","<\/")` should do the trick, no?

Comment: @Sam Saffron: Yes, using a backslash also works for preventing the `</` character combination. You can use a backslash before any character, even if the character has no special meaning that requires it to be escaped.

Comment: All fair points in this answer, but @Sam Saffron, beware of the CDATA solution: it really *only* works if you’re *actually* using XHTML, which is very unlikely. Specifying an XHTML doctype is not enough. Read [Sending XHTML as text/html Considered Harmful](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml).

Comment: If you’re already relying on actual XHTML being used, what’s the point in those extra “`//`”s before “`<![CDATA[`” and “`]]>`”? ☺

Answer (score 6):

See [OWASP's XSS prevention guide](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_JavaScript_Data_Values) (See Rule #3) -

> Except for alphanumeric characters,
>   escape all characters less than 256
>   with the \xHH format to prevent
>   switching out of the data value into
>   the script context or into another
>   attribute. Do not use any escaping
>   shortcuts like \" because the quote
>   character may be matched by the HTML
>   attribute parser which runs first.

Assume this is how your object looks like -

```
var log = {
trace: function(m1, m2, m3){},
debug: function(m1, m2, m3){},
currentLogValue : "trace {].a23-%\/^&",
someOtherObject : {someKey:"somevalue", someOtherKey:"someothervalue"}
};
```

This should end up like this -

```
var log = {
trace : "function\x28m1,\x20m2,\x20m3\x29\x7B\x7D",
debug : "function\x28m1,\x20m2,\x20m3\x29\x7B\x7D",
currentLogValue : "trace\x20\x7B\x5D.a23\x2D\x25\x5C\x2F\x5E\x26",
someOtherObject : {someKey : "somevalue", someOtherKey:"someothervalue"}
};
```

The rules are straightforward -

1. Untrusted data is only allowed within a pair of quotes
2. Whatever is within quotes gets escaped as follows - "Except alphanumeric characters, escape everything else with the \xHH format"

This ensures that untrusted data is always interpreted as a string, and not as a function/object/anything else.

Answer (score 2):

In literal strings, put a backslash (`\`) before all “unsafe” characters, including the forward slash which occurs in “`</script>`” (`/` → `\/`).

This would change your example to:

```
json = {test: "<\/script><script>alert(\"hello\");<\/script>"};
```

and it would still be valid JSON.

Of course you also have to escape the double-quote (`"` → `\"`) and the backslash itself (`\` → `\\`), but you would already have to do that anyway. You should also consider escaping the single-quote (`'` → `\'`) to be on the safe side.

Comment: so a simple replace("/", "\/") should do ? any other edge cases ?

Comment: @Sam Saffron: Yes, take care of double-quotes, single-quotes, and backslashes. See my edited answer.

Comment: cool, yerp I already had those encoded, expanding my question with a slightly hairier sample.

Comment: There is nothing unsafe with the forward slash. The reason that this works is that it prevents the character combination `</`, which ends the script tag.

Comment: @Guffa: I know. There is nothing unsafe with the forward slash *itself*, but there *is* something unsafe with the character sequence `</script>`, so escaping the slash makes it safe.

Answer (score 2):

One issue you might be running into is the fact that the HTML and javascript interpreters on the browser run interleaved.

```
<html> 
<body>
<script>
 json = {test: "</script><script>alert('hello');</script>"};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your example, the HTML interpreter will give `json = {test: "` to the js interpreter and then it will find the next javascript block (delimited by `<script>` and `</script>` tags) and give `alert('hello');` to the js interpreter. It doesn't matter that the `</script>` tag is in a javascript string, because the HTML interpreter is the one looking for js code blocks and doesn't understand js strings.

The first section will cause a js syntax error, while the second section will create the alert. I realize this doesn't answer your question of what to do, but perhaps it will shed more light on what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983451/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-escape-characters-required-for-my-json-ajax-return-typ/1021976#1021976) list of characters to be escaped for JSON strings:

```
\b  Backspace (ascii code 08)
\f  Form feed (ascii code 0C)
\n  New line
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\v  Vertical tab
\'  Apostrophe or single quote
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```

Using PHP? If so: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
 echo json_encode("<\/script><script>alert(\"hello\");<\/script>");
```

Output:

```
 "<\\\/script><script>alert(\"hello\");<\\\/script>"
```

Another example:

```
 echo json_encode("</script><script>alert(\"hello\");</script>");
```

Output:

```
 "<\/script><script>alert(\"hello\");<\/script>"
```

Comment: Does that escape the forward slash? The help page doesn’t say. (In fact, it doesn’t say what *any* of the options mean.)

Comment: Added example, looks like it does escape the forward slash :)

Comment: can you expand on the algorithm I should use? I am not using PHP

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, Michael — I kept editing and deleting my comment. I should have paid more attention. But this is all irrelevant now that Sam has elucidated that he is not using PHP.