# Hive and get_json_object strange behavior

Tags: json, hive

I am running hive query using get_json_object to read json strings from files in HDFS.
And I bumped with some strange behavior:
if the json is as follow:

```
{"data":{"oneSlash":"aaa\bbb","twoSlashes":"ccc\\ddd","threeSlashes":"eee\\\fff"}}
```

The result of the query is:

```
{"oneSlash":"aaabbb","twoSlashes":"ccc\\ddd","threeSlashes":"eee\\fff"}
```

I understand the 'oneSlash' and the 'threeSlashes' result but why 'twoSlashes' did not equal to "ccc\ddd"?
after all '\' should be unescaped to '\'

BTW the quesry is:

```
SELECT get_json_object(escaping_test.data, '$.data') FROM escaping_test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because \b and \f is valid escape characters whereas \d is not. there's a post about this in more detail: [Where can I find a list of escape characters required for my JSON ajax return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983451/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-escape-characters-required-for-my-json-ajax-return-ty)