# How to add "\" character in JSON?

Tags: javascript

I want to add JSON data with the following string value:

```
json = "d:\xyz\abc";
```

This value is coming from a database at runtime. When I am going to display it in datatable, JSON formatting error is displayed. My requirement is that the above value will be displayed as it is in the datatable. Please help.

Comment: How are you creating your JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better use a JSON library for your programming language. You don't retrieve database values directly with jquery, aren't you?

So, you'd use something like `JSON.escape(my_string_from_db)`, or, in Ruby language I usually do `my_string.to_json`.

This will automatically escape everything that needs to be escaped.

Comment: Where from I get these lib? I get some java classes but not jar file.

Answer (score 7):

Escape it with another `\`:

```
var json = "d:\\xyz\\abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
json = "d:\\xyz\\abc";
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983451/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-escape-characters-required-for-my-json-ajax-return-ty) question for further information

Answer (score 0):

`\` is the escape character in JavaScript strings, it gives special meaning to the character following the slash. Like `\t` is a tab character, `\n` is a new line. To put a backslash literal you'll need to use `\\`

The first backslash says the next character is going to be special, the following backslash says "oh, it's just a backslash."