# Parsing JSON containing new line characters

Tags: javascript, json

In my website I try to convert a string to JSON which contains a newline.

```
JSON.parse('{"hallo":"line1\r\nline2","a":[5.5,5.6,5.7]}');
```

This produces an "Unexpected token" error. Do I need to escape that somehow?

Comment: Why do you write JSON manually?

Comment: I don't! The json line is beeing generated by another program which obviously doesn't escape those characters correctly.

Comment: In that case the program is correct and you placed `JSON.parse('` and `');` manually. The program's output is likely `{"hallo":"line1\r\nline2","a":[5.5,5.6,5.7]}` which is correct. You do not need to make a javascript string out of it, it's already valid javascript in an expression context by itself. All you needed was `var a = programOutput;` directly without any interference.

Comment: No, the programs output is exactly this line including JSON.parse; whoever made it had obviously no idea about JavaScript

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, you should escape both `\n` and `\r` as they belong to the list of control characters. Full list of characters that need to be escaped can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021976/822789). Your code would be

```
obj = JSON.parse('{"hallo":"line1\\r\\nline2","a":[5.5,5.6,5.7]}');
```

JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fFcxf/1/)

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it contains an extra line of "explanation" :P

Comment: Silly me. I only tried escaping the \n and totally forgot about the \r. Thank you, it is working now.

Comment: is there a function to escape those characters?

Comment: Actually, I had to "double escape" to have the new line reaching the HTML. I take the value from the database then do a replaceAll("\n","\\\\n").reaplaceAll("\r","\\\\r") and all is fine now :D

Comment: @Throoze - yes, there is. JSON.stringify(str) will return a string containing a quoted, escaped JS string literal for `str`. For example, `JSON.stringify("\n").length` evaluates to `4`, because the returned string will have two quotes, a backslash and an `n`, just like the literal passed into it.

Comment: Am I missing something here? I'm not seeing two lines in the fiddle link.

Comment: What if the string to parse is incoming from another service ? how do I dynamically parse any given string with `\n` and `\r` in it ?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
JSON.parse('{"hallo":"line1\\r\\nline2","a":[5.5,5.6,5.7]}');
```