# NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData where data contains line break characters

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

**Sample Code:**

```
NSString *jsonObject = ...;
BOOL isValidJSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonObject];
id jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:parsedData
                                                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                  error:&jsonError];
```

**Issue:**

If `jsonObject` contains string data with newline characters, then `NSJSONSerialization` fails to parse and return a valid `jsonRespone` object. It returns following error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unescaped control character around character 119.) UserInfo=0x10ba9fef0 {NSDebugDescription=Unescaped control character around character 119.}
```

Sample JSON String (with newline character):

```
{"Name" : "Lorum","Description" : "Sample: 
Lorum ipsum","Quantity" : 1,"Type" : 1}
```

What's the best way to handle this situation? Newline/ line break character should be valid in this case.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Newlines should be escaped.

Comment: Hope help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591784/parsing-json-containing-new-line-characters

Comment: @duci9y When you say "escape" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: For now, I just changed newline with <br> tag, and then replaced <br> with newline (at application end). Alternately, I could have encoded the data. I don't like this approach. I think NSJSONSerialization should handle the newline characters (\n and \r). JSONKit handles this with the option JKParseOptionUnicodeNewlines, and I like that!

Comment: JSONKit provides that option for you as a favor. Your JSON would still be incorrect according to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

YES, double backslash is needed. However slash is not need to write twice.
For example,

`jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@[@"line 0\nline1", @"http://twitter.com"] options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

when hover your cursor on `jsonString`, Xcode will tell you what it exactly want. If you write

`jsonString = @"[\"http://twitter.com\"]"`,

you can get correct answer when using NSJSONSerialization to parse the string. Even you know the more suitable input is

`jsonString = @"[\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\"]"`.