# New line in JSON String wont work in chrome emulator

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to insert newline between strings in json,but didnt work.Here is the code
{ `id: 0, address: "First line\r\nsecond line" },`

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591784/parsing-json-containing-new-line-characters)

Comment: this is painfullly less amount of information. please elaborate what you mean when you say didn't work.. you can validate your json here http://jsonlint.org

Comment: Stop saying "didn't work". That tells us nothing at all. JSON Lint _does_ "work" so you did something wrong, and you've given us no information to determine what that something is.

Comment: @UncleKing return the console error `Parse error on line 2:
[    {        id: 0,        name:
--------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'`

Comment: jsonlint throws error for your string -- did you considering the adding quotes to your keys ? { "id": 0, "address": "First line\r\nsecond line" } ... still there is no information on your environment and what you mean by error or how youare trying to give this input to chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem using `ng-bind-html`in angular js.Here is my update code

```
{ id: 0, address: "First line<br>second line" }
```

in my html `<p ng-bind-html="friends.address"></p>`

```
Result:

    First line
    second line
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine when the JSON is parsed and printed. It just doesn't appear as an actual newline when viewed as an Object.

```
var a = { id: 0, address: "First line\r\nsecond line" }
  -> Object {id: 0, address: "First line↵second line"}

console.log(a.address)
  -> First line
     second line
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2wyfwoum/1/

Comment: @404 What is chrome emulator? I've given you an example.