# Issue: JSON mapping text with accented characters

Tags: json, swift

I have a problem with JSON. I have a Rest API to return a list of objects. This object have text with enter and tittle (ó) and the text have "\U00f3n", "\n", I can't map this to a text.

I convert the result in JSON like this:

```
let jsonResult: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err)
```

I map the result to text like this:

```
func parseNew(pNew: AnyObject)->New 
{
  if let description = pNew["Text"] as? String
  {
      newRetorno.setText(description)
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this "newRetorno.setText"? Additionally, your syntax is broken. The first line should be "let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization(data: data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err)"

Comment: @JohnDifool ??? OP's syntax is working, yours is not. Check in a Playground.

Comment: Ah! The beauty of running on XCode Beta 7! Apple apparently continues to polish their bridged API between ObjC & Swift.

Comment: @JohnDifool  the line newRetorno.setText() is other thing, no matter

Comment: Got it. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591784/parsing-json-containing-new-line-characters for handling JSON which include nl.