# Large JSON String not parsing using JSON.parse or angular.fromJson

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing

I'm trying to replace the angularjs POST query with standalone JSON response string.

When angular GET / POST queries returns a response automatically converted to JSON and the code was working like charm.

Now, I'm trying to have the json response stored as a javascript string variable in the controller and then trying to parse it using `JSON.stringify()` and subsequently using `JSON.parse()`.

There is no error but the resulting json object's member variables can't be accessed using the `.` operator

```
var staticData = '{"someKey":"someValue", "masterJobs":[]}'; //very large json string.
var resultString = JSON.stringify(staticData);
$scope.staticTestData = JSON.parse(resultString);
console.log($scope.staticTestData.masterJobs); // this displays 'undefined'
```

Controller function with the [large JSON is available here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5jg7Xaama_jAxy-46YbzxxUI3L).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a string, so there is no need to use `JSON.stringify`.

Just use the following code:

```
var staticData = '{"someKey":"someValue", "masterJobs":[]}'; //very large json string.
$scope.staticTestData = JSON.parse(staticData);
console.log($scope.staticTestData.masterJobs);
```

Comment: I tried that already. This is the error I get when I parse the string without doing the JSON.stringify() <br/> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
 in JSON at position 1323
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at searchFunction (SummaryReport.html:249)
    at new <anonymous> (SummaryReport.html:262)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
    at P.instance (angular.min.js:89)
    at n (angular.min.js:65)
    at g (angular.min.js:58)
    at angular.min.js:58
    at angular.min.js:21
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)

Comment: Have a look at the exact position of the error and you will find this section `"tsdescription":"<br>DISPLAYED<br>\n<br>\nPassed"`. It contains new lines `\n` which will cause your string to actually have new lines in it (and not inside the value). You need to escape them, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591784/parsing-json-containing-new-line-characters for details.

Comment: That helped!! But it is now failing at this point: 

"xmlLogFilePath": "\\\\cable.comcast.com\\corp-dfs\\CHQ-Shared\\BSD-TCoE\\Logs\\WEBTOP\\TACGWC-WBTP02\\Parent_WEBTOP_ONECLICK_MASTER_8\\testng_simon_SimonMACD_OneClick"

Do you see anything wrong with the escaped url?