# HTML format text in json

Tags: json, cdata, htmltext

How can I get a html format text through json, like below format?

```
<div class="header" id="header_1">
 <p>All glitters are not gold</p>
</div>
```

Because json doesn't support " character inside the object value.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape quotes in JSON with `\"`

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021976/1310220) for a list of all JSON escape characters.