# Is there a way to parse mustache HTML template and generate JSON structure from it, that can used to feed such templates?

Tags: html, handlebars.js, html-parsing, mustache

Say i have below html template

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>{{tested.object1}}</p>
    <p>{{tested.object2}}</p>
    <p>{{testedn.[0].object3}}</p>
</body>
```

Is there a way i can parse through it and generate required json payload/structure that can be used to feed this/such templates. In this case:

```
{ tested: { object1: '', object2: '' }, testedn: { '0': { object3: '' } } }
```

Most of the searches i did are leading to ways in which i can feed a already available json to such html templates. But nothing for other way around.

i have checked jMustache but couldnt find what i am looking for. Are there any leads on how i can achieve above in java?

Answer (score 0):

Mustache or Handlebar is clearly not designed to do such a thing. You may try intead to convert your html flow to json using serialization.
Try this post [How to convert selected HTML to Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504050/how-to-convert-selected-html-to-json)