# Parsing path in JSON

Tags: c++, json, parsing, rapidjson

I'm trying to pass a JSON object containing a `path` from my frontend (Node) to the backend (C++) using RapidJSON, like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

int main() {
  const char* json1 = "{\"path\":\"C:\\test.file\"}";                     // works
  const char* json2 = "{\"path\":\"C:\\fol der\\test.file\"}";            // works
  const char* json3 = "{\"path\":\"C:\\fol der\\Test.file\"}";            // ERROR!
  const char* json4 = "{\"path\":\"C:\\few dol\\test.file\"}";            // ERROR!
  const char* json5 = "{\"path\":\"C:\\folder\\anotherOne\\test.file\"}"; // ERROR!
  rapidjson::Document d;
  d.Parse(json3);    // works using json1 or json2
  assert(d.HasMember("path"));
  std::string pathString = d["path"].GetString();
  return 0;
}
```

The first two strings work. However, I can't get any longer paths to work and even capitalization is giving me trouble (the only difference between `json2` and `json3` is the "**T**").

How do I properly pass and parse paths (Windows and maybe Linux)?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** I just tried [nlohman's JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and have the same problem.

**How do I pass paths in JSON???**

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is the path not a valid path? or your assertions are failing?

Comment: @Kartoos : The resulting `Document` is null (e.g. `d.Parse(json3)` ). So the assertion afterwards fails as well, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print your json variables you will get the following (C++ interprets the escape characters):

```
json1: {"path":"C:\test.file"}
json2: {"path":"C:\fol der\test.file"}
json3: {"path":"C:\fol der\Test.file"}
json4: {"path":"C:\few dol\test.file"}
json5: {"path":"C:\folder\anotherOne\test.file"}
```

Now you can test these json in any tool like https://jsonlint.com/, you will get errors. the reason for error is that the strings represented by "path" in the case of `json3` and `json5` are not valid string because of invalid escape characters present in them.

Here is the list of escape sequences per string: 
`json1` has `\t` 
`json2` has `\f` and `\t` 
`json3` has `\f` and `\T` 
`json4` has `\f` and `\t` 
`json5` has `\f` and `\a` and `\t`

Among all of these escape characters, `\T` and `\a` are invalid and hence `json3` and `json5` are invalid as well.

Now, if you want to parse it properly, then one simple way could be using four backslashes `\\\\` for example:

```cpp
const char* json3 = "{\"path\":\"C:\\\\fol der\\\\Test.file\"}";
```

which will be equivalent to `C:\fol der\Test.file`

Comment: For list of escape characters see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983451/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-escape-characters-required-for-my-json-ajax-return-ty

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I also just found out about `R"()"`, which then "only" requires double backslashes.

Comment: gr8... I was also thinking there must be some way to interpret the string as raw... I think you have found it :)