# What means this regular expression \r\n?

Tags: json, expression

```
"raw": "{\r\n    \"correo\": \"tads@gmail.com\",\r\n    \"password\": \"654321\"\r\n}"
```

These fields I need to understand to be able to make a post request

I do not understand this expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a list of escape characters required for my JSON ajax return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983451/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-escape-characters-required-for-my-json-ajax-return-ty) -- answers describe both `\r` and `\n`. (Note that these aren't unique to JSON -- they have the same meaning in common string types in C, Python, Java, Go, &c as well).

Comment: Also, note that carriage-return+newline is a sequence from the Windows world; in the UNIX world the newline itself stands alone. Regardless, your data would probably work just as well as `"raw": "{\"correo\": \"tads@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"654321\"}"` with no `\r` or `\n` at all.

Comment: (Also, they're not regular expressions at all in the first place)

Answer (score 1):

`\r` is the [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character.
`\n` is the [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character.

`raw` in this case includes an escaped JSON as a string.